# Proper use of multilevel analysis in team settings [conceptual question]

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

i am faced with the following question: I sit on a data-set of about 200 teams, that contains information about the mental health of the individuals (i.e., GHQ-12, ex: sleeplessness and so on.) and other information such as collective or team helping behavior. Helping behavior was measured by asking each team member about the shared perception of helping within a team (a so called referent-shift consensus model framework; Chan, 1998). It is a shared mental model, and therefore it needs consensus of the team-members in order to exist. One ex. question is "we help each other..."

So far so good. Now the idea is that team helping at the workplace should reduce the impact of work related strain and therefore decrease GHQ-12 related symptomatology of the individual within the team. However, the more i read into HLM, i feel that it is not the proper method. While team-helping is a Level 2 variable and GHQ sits at L1, i feel because the way team-helping is conceptualized (shared mental model) i am better served aggregating the L2 variable and then regress it onto the dependent, rather than use something like this:

```
lmer(ghq ~ covariate + team.helping + (1|team.id)
```

So the question would be: is MLM the right approach here, or should i stick to my old guns?

Greetings, 
G.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal, then MLM is exactly what you need. Consider what is happening in an MLM, which is easiest to see if I write out an equation level-by-level:

Level 1: $y_{ij} = B_{0j} + B_1*X(covariate)_{ij} + e_{ij}$

Level 2: $B_{0j} = y_{00} + y_{01}*Z(team.helping)_j + u_{0j}$

As you can see, the team.helping predictor influences the group's ghq intercept (B0j) whereas the covariate, assuming it is measured at the lowest level of the hierarchy, is predominantly influencing each individual's ghq score. Note that in MLMs, level 1 variables likely have variance at level 2 as well, and so you might consider adding the group mean of the covariate to the level 2 equation. In R, you could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(lme4)
group_by(df$team.id) %>% mutate(df$mn_cov = mean(df$covariate)) %>% ungroup() 
m1 <- lmer(ghq ~ covariate + mn_cov + team.helping + (1|team.id), df)
```